# The difference between ω and A?

Tags: probability

In a probability course, I have the following expression:

> For a countable infinite set, we define the event
>    $$\bigcup_{i\in I}\{\omega\in\Omega\mid \exists i\in I,\omega\in A_i\}$$

What I can't understand is the difference between $\omega$ and $A$, aren't they both an event? Doesn't that mean that $\omega$ belongs to $A_i$ has no sense?

Comment: In measure-theoretic probability, an event is a measurable subset of $\Omega $. Sometimes the elements of $\Omega $ are called elementary events but this should really be used to refer to singleton subsets of $\Omega $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probability space is a triple $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ where $\Omega$ is the set of outcomes, $\mathcal F$ is $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ and $P\colon \mathcal F\to [0,1]$ probability measure. Now, $\omega$ is usually element of $\Omega$, while $A$ is element of $\mathcal F$. We measure elements of $\mathcal F$, not elements of $\Omega$.

Let me give an example. Let $\Omega = [0,1]$, $\mathcal F$ [Borel $\sigma$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set) on $[0,1]$ ($\sigma$-algebra generated by open intervals) and $\mu$ [Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure) (in simple terms, length). Now, it makes sense to ask what is the length of $[0,1]$, $\langle 0.2,0.75\rangle$ and even $\{1\}$, but it doesn't make sense to ask what is the length of number $1$, for example. Notice how $[0,1]$, $\langle 0.2,0.75\rangle$ and $\{1\}$ are elements of $\mathcal F$, while $1$ is not, $1\in\Omega$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so saying ω belongs to Ai is like 1 belongs to [0,1] right? so can you give me an example where the expression (in the picture of the main post) isn't true?

Comment: @saywow, there is nothing untrue in the picture, $A_i$'s are (highly likely) subsets of $\Omega$, so naturally, they contain some $\omega\in\Omega$. This is just a definition of [set union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)).